# Show that $\displaystyle\prod_{\Bbb{N}} \Bbb{R}$ with the box topology is Hausdorff but not metrizable.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Show that $\displaystyle\prod_{\Bbb{N}} \Bbb{R}$ with the box topology is Hausdorff but not metrizable.

$\Bbb{R}$ must be Hausdorff. For $x_1, x_2 \in \Bbb{R}$ (where $x_1 \not= x_2$), if $d$ denotes the distance between these two points, then we can choose an open ball $U_1$ with radius $d/2$ around $x_1$ and an open ball $U_2$ again of radius $d/2$ around $x_2$. Obviously, these two open balls will not intersect at any point.

So let $(x_1, x_2, ...), (x'_1, x'_2, ...) \in \Bbb{R^n}$. Then For each $x_i, x'_i \in \Bbb{R}$ (where $i \in \Bbb{N}$), there exist open balls $U_i$ and $U'_i$  in $\Bbb{R}$ around $x_i$ and $x'_i$, respectively, such that the open balls do not intersect. But then $(U_1 \times U_2 \times ...) \cap (U'_1 \times U'_2 \times ...) = \emptyset$.

We can show that $\displaystyle\prod_{\Bbb{N}} \Bbb{R}$ is not metrizable by proving that it is not first countable.

The first countability condition tells us that $\forall x \in X$ $\exists \{ U_n \}_{n\ \in \Bbb{N}} \subseteq  P(X)$ such that

(i) $\forall n \in \Bbb{N}$, $U_n$ is a neighborhood of $x$.

(ii) For every neighborhood $V$ of $x$ $\exists n \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $U_n \subseteq V$.

So let's pick the point $(0,0,0,...) \in \displaystyle\prod_{\Bbb{N}} \Bbb{R}$. We know that, for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$ (in each $\Bbb{R}$) $(-1/n, 1/n)$ is a neighborhood of $0$.

So $(\frac{-1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}) \times (\frac{-1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}) \times (\frac{-1}{n}, \frac{1}{n})...$ is a neighborhood of $(0,0,0,0,...)$.

But in order to have $U_n \in \{U_n\}_{n \in \Bbb{N}}$ such that $U_n \subseteq (\frac{-1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}) \times (\frac{-1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}) \times (\frac{-1}{n}, \frac{1}{n})...$ for all $n$, we know that the sequence $\{(\frac{-1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}) \times (\frac{-1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}) \times (\frac{-1}{n}, \frac{1}{n})...\}_{n \in \Bbb{N}} = \{U_n\}_{n \in \Bbb{N}}$.

But a sequences approaches infinity, and as $n \rightarrow \infty$ $(\frac{-1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}) \times (\frac{-1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}) \times (\frac{-1}{n}, \frac{1}{n})... = \{0\} \times \{0\} \times ...$, which is a closed neighborhood of $(0,0,0,...)$, meaning that the 1st condition of first countability fails.

Is my answer correct? If not, can anybody give me a hint?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the definition of limit of open sets? It is well-defined concept?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your solution to Hausdorffness is not quite correct.  Note what happens if your points are $\mathbf{x} = \langle  1 , 2, 3, \ldots \rangle$ and $\mathbf{x^\prime} = \langle 3 , 3 , 3 , \ldots \rangle$.  (How do you choose the neighbourhoods $U_3$ and $U^\prime_3$?)

Recall that the usual product topology on $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ is Hausdorff.  Perhaps we can use this fact (or the proof of this fact.)

---

Your solution to the non-first-countability of the space is also somewhat off.  You appear to be showing that *one* particular countable family of neighbourhoods of $\mathbf{0} = \langle 0 , 0 , \ldots \rangle$ is not a neighbourhood base.  But you instead have to show that *every* countable family of neighbourhoods of $\mathbf{0}$ is not a neighbourhood base.

What you want to do is start with any old countably family $\{ U_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ of open neighbourhoods of $\mathbf{0}$, and produce an open neighbourhood $V$ of $\mathbf{0}$ for which $U_n \not\subseteq V$ holds for all $n$.  As a particularly strong hint, produce $V$ so that for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the projection of $V$ onto the $n$th coordinate is a proper subset of the projection of $U_n$ onto the $n$th coordinate.

Comment: For the first one, we can say that there must be at least one $k \in \Bbb{N}$, such that $x_k \not= x'_k$. So we can choose the open balls so that $U_k \cap U'_k = \emptyset$. Now suppose, for contradiction, that $(y_1, y_2, ... ) \in \displaystyle\prod_{i \in \Bbb{N}} U_i \cap \displaystyle\prod_{i \in \Bbb{N}} U'_i$. But then $y_k \in U_k \cap U'_k$, a contradiction.

Comment: For the second one, we can construct an open neighborhood **V** = $V_1 \times V_2 \times ...$ of **0**, such that, for each $i \in \Bbb{N}$, the ith coordinate of **V** has half the radius of the ith coordinate of $U_i$. Now if we suppose that, for some $k \in \Bbb{N}$, $U_k \subseteq $ **V**. We get a contradiction, because the $k$th coordinate of **V** is smaller than that of $U_k$, right?

Comment: @Artus: You should be a little more specific about what $U_i$ and $U_i'$ are when $i\ne k$; the simplest solution is to let them be $\Bbb R$. Your idea for non-first-countability is correct.

Comment: @Artus: Sorry, I've been away from math.SE for a bit.  I agree with everything that Brian has said above: you were on the right track with Hausdorffness, but a slight fix makes things easier.  And your idea for non-first-countability appears to be exactly what I was thinking.

Answer (score 4):

For not metrizable:let $A$ be the set of all sequences with elements in $\mathbb{R}$ with the property that the elements of all these sequences are positive .now the zero sequence(the sequence with zero elements) is a closure point for $A$ because every open set in $\displaystyle\prod_{\Bbb{N}} \Bbb{R}$ has a form $U_1 \times U_2 \times ...$ s,t $U_i$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ and if $U_1 \times U_2 \times ...$ is an open set contains the zero sequence,then its intersection with $A$ is nonempty.

We assume that there exist a sequence ${a_n}$ tends to the zero sequence and $a_n$={$x^n_m$}$_{m\in\mathbb{N}}$.
Now $(-x^1_1,x^1_1)\times (-x^2_2,x^2_2)\times (-x^3_3,x^3_3)...$ Is an Open set contains the zero sequence but It contains no member of the sequence ${a_n}$.

from $\color{red}{Munkres's}\space topology$.

Comment: You have shown that $0$ is a closure point for $A$, and yet no sequence converges to it. Why does this mean non-metrizable?

Comment: @AAN4EVA Use the sequence lemma, which states (from Munkres): "Let $X$ be a topological space; let $A \subset X$. If there is a sequence of points of $A$ converging to $x$, then $x \in \bar{A}$; the converse holds if $X$ is metrizable." Since the converse does not hold, $X$ is not metrizable.